# Lycanthropy and elves - what is the general guideline?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, pathfinder-1e

Well, to get to the point. AFAIK, lycanthropy is mostly reserved for humans and, from what I gained from the books, elves are immune to it as it is a human disease. I recall seeing somewhere a template for elf lycanthropy, but I can't remember where. What I distinctly recall is that it is possible and it required a ritual. Also, a character must be willing and it had only animal form, no hybrid form. I also believe the alignment was lawful or chaotic good. IIRC it was caled a lycant or something like that.

Has anyone else ran across a similar problem or template that can be used? Or, if someone knows where I can find the template described above.

I'm making a character for a session and I would like to come with something substantial to my GM as I would like to play an elf druid/lycanthrope...

Comment: IIRC, I think there was a reference in Races/Monsters of Faerun... I checked later, the term was Lythari... I found it here: http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Lythari but I think it is a 3rd edition variant

Comment: Well, 3 and 3.5 do share certain portability. And apparently the Lythari is referenced in the Frostfell book. Mechanically it seems that you just use the werewolf template but lose your hybrid form. From a game PoV this seems like a trivial change allowable by the DM. From a mechanical point of view, I believe it's better simulated by your beast form as druid than as a template.

Comment: true... well, I will look into it.. maybe I could convince my GM to incorporate it into my class somehow... will see... btw. could the elves get lycanthropy in the 3rd edition also?

Comment: @Silaqui I'm pretty sure that was the case.  I'm not sure where you got the idea they couldn't, perhaps a homebrew game?

Comment: @C.Ross To be honest, I don't know.. I'm sure I read it somewhere.. It was in the same group as ghoul paralysis, sleep and similar stuff, which don't affect elves...

Comment: How did the character go? Would you mind answering the question with the resources you used?

Comment: Maybe you're remembering from an earlier version of the game? How did lycanthropy work in AD&D?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*As your question is tagged for both 3.5 and Pathfinder I'll answer for both.*

For 3.5 check out the *Savage Species* splat-book, as Brian noted. It gives a level by level breakdown over the course of 6 levels for how to turn a PC into a Werewolf, though I believe there are some other Lycanthropes listed as well. While [this](http://www.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/sp/20040117a) isn't the *Savage Species* breakdown I was referencing, WOTC released a "Savage Progressions" series on their site breaking down monster races into playable classes. It is worth looking into as you can invest as much or as little as you want into it if you just want the flavor.

For Pathfinder, with DM approval, you could always take the [CR+1 Lycanthrope template](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/lycanthrope) listed on the Pathfinder SRD (and in the back of the *Bestiary*.) Essentially it'd be a 2 level multi-class dip but you'd get the flavor you are looking for without wasting levels and still remain an effective Druid. The template itself is for both natural and afflicted Lycanthropes with varying levels of power for each type. [Here](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/lycanthrope/werewolf) is the Pathfinder Werewolf in all of its glory if that is the route you are wanting to go, just to give you a better idea of what your Druid would be capable of.

Personally, I have gone both routes at one point or the other. The *Savage Species* breakdowns are nice and effective but at the cost of a significant level investment. It can feel like your uber-powerful character is weaker than your regular party members at times. I would just go the template route, personally. The level investment is less significant and you still get the flavor you want out of it. Before you decide on either though, I'd talk with your DM just to run it by him as he might have a preference either way.

Comment: Why mention only *Savage Species*, and not the Core approach to 3.5 lycanthropy?

Answer (score 9):

D20SRD specific answer,

Most weres in D&D can be from any humanoid basis. Quoth the [SRD](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/lycanthrope.htm):

> Lycanthropes are humanoids or giants who can transform themselves into animals. In its natural form, a lycanthrope looks like any other members of its kind, though natural lycanthropes and those who have been afflicted for a long time tend to have or acquire features reminiscent of their animal forms. In animal form, a lycanthrope resembles a powerful version of the normal animal, but on close inspection, its eyes (which often glow red in the dark) show a faint spark of unnatural intelligence.

...

> "Lycanthrope" is a template that can be added to any humanoid or giant (referred to hereafter as the base creature). The lycanthrope template can be inherited (for natural lycanthropes) or acquired (for afflicted lycanthropes). Becoming a lycanthrope is very much like multiclassing as an animal and gaining the appropriate Hit Dice.

Therefore, elves should have no problem using the lycanthrope template, though there may be some setting-specific restrictions.

Beyond that, there are a number of options within Savage Species that should allow for a humanoid to be mixed with a animal, up to and including creating your own template. A [Lycan](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/Lycan,_Lore_Variant_%283.5e_Template%29) does not seem to be what you think it is (though that is a homebrew template...) there seem to be few other lycanthrope templates floating around, though I do recommend the [low-power lycanthrope](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/Low-Power_Lycanthrope_%283.5e_Template%29) perhaps you're thinking of an ebberon shifter?